# pyqt4 customize qlistwidget item

Tags: pyqt4

Im trying to customize qlistwidgetitem but there is a overlap between the text and the button.

Here is my code.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

import sys


class myListWidget(QListWidget):

    def Clicked(self, item):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "ListWidget", "You clicked: "+item.text())

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    listWidget = myListWidget()
    #Resize width and height
    listWidget.resize(300,120)
    l = QListWidgetItem()
    l.setText('Im an item')
    l.setFlags(l.flags() | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
    l.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
    button = QCheckBox('Hello')
    l.setSizeHint(button.minimumSizeHint())
    listWidget.addItem(l)
    listWidget.setItemWidget(l, button)

    listWidget.setWindowTitle('PyQT QListwidget Demo')
    listWidget.itemClicked.connect(listWidget.Clicked)

    listWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

[image]

Reqt:-

[image]

Comment: How do you want it to be displayed? A widget assigned to an item of the QListWidget is superimposed on the item.

Comment: I want the button to be displayed on the right side(justified) not super imposed.

Comment: the item is checkeable and also the button is a QCheckBox: `l.setFlags(l.flags() | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)`, do you want to have 2 checkbox in the same item?

Comment: yes, thats correct, both checkbox will have different meanings

Comment: You want to have 2 QCheckBox in the same box, am I right?

Comment: no, checkbox with a label and then append a checkbox to it.

Comment: I still do not know what you want, I can see that it has 2 texts: `Im an item` and`Hello`, to which of these texts do you refer?

Comment: Its superimposed, I want the 'Hello' checkbox to be displayed at the end(right justified)

Comment: I added a screen shot to show how it looks on my ubuntu machine..I want the checkbox to be separate, now when I hover the checkbox(with hello), I don't see the "Im an item" text

Comment: I also observe it, to understand correctly you could show an image of what you want to obtain.

Comment: I have added the reqt pic, checkbox, label, checkbox..The label is associated to the left checkbox, so it should be adjacent to it.